# Is it possible to start an IPython notebook and QT-console working with the same kernel with one click?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to be able to start IPython notebook and a QTconsole connected to the same kernel. Theoretically, I can launch one of them, get kernel info and then connect the another one to that kernel. However, I would like to be able to do this in one command (I work on Windows). Is that possible?

Note: the documentation says that I can start qtconsole from a notebook using `%qtconsole` command. However, in my case I get the following error "ERROR: Could not start qtconsole: ValueError('close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr',)"

Comment: From the notebook, you can use the `%qtconsole` magic to start a Qt console attached to the same kernel. It's not quite one command, but it's close.

Comment: @ThomasK this doesn't work in my case, see the note

Comment: What version of IPython do you have? That should have been fixed: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running the latest IPython 2.1 with Anaconda 2.0.1.

There are some [directions on this page](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/public_server.html) which help you set up a IPython instance for hosting purposes.  Here is how to tweak this to run locally.

run "`ipython profile create nbserver`" at the terminal/command prompt

In the profile directory just created, (usually ~/.ipython/profile_nbserver) edit the file ipython_notebook_config.py. By default, the file has all fields commented; the minimum set you need to uncomment and edit is the following:

```
c = get_config()

# Kernel config
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'  # if you want plotting support always

# Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'               #or keep it 'localhost'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
# It is a good idea to put it on a known, fixed port
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
```

Then open 2 terminals/command_prompts so you can check if it works.  In the first type (don't put an underscore in either line)

```
ipython console -i --profile nbserver
```

then type in that window `a = 1`

and the 2nd

```
ipython console -i --profile nbserver --existing
```

type `print(a)`

**and yes... you can replace the word "console" with "notebook" or "qtconsole"** 
(but for qt-console take out the -i switch)

Since you are on windows you could put those 2 commands in a script.

Comment: cool, this works with the default profile too -- no need to create a new profile. Running ` ipython3 console -i --existing` does the job